# Авторские знаки пунктуации

Tags: запятая

Допустимо ли оставить указанную авторскую запятую? Или здесь лучше применить парцелляцию?

По сути, сама формулировка говорит о том, что нельзя просто внедрить «Бережливое
производство», к нему нужно стремиться (,) постоянно, планомерно, не останавливаясь на достигнутом.

По сути, сама формулировка говорит о том, что нельзя просто внедрить «Бережливое
производство». К нему нужно стремиться. Постоянно. Планомерно. Не останавливаясь на достигнутом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Аленка, понятие "авторские знаки препинания" еще не означают, что автор может ставить их там, где ему хочется. В вашем примере указанная "авторская"запятая поставлена некорректна, т.к. наряду со словами "постоянно", "планомерно" создает интонацию перечисления, а это нарушает строй и смысл предложения. 
  Корректно: По сути, сама формулировка говорит о том, что нельзя просто внедрить «Бережливое производство. К нему нужно стремиться. Постоянно. Планомерно. Не останавливаясь на достигнутом. Парцелляция применяется для большой выразительности, экспрессивности, выделение важных важных деталей. 
Но можно использовать и другую конструкцию: <...>К нему нужно стремиться постоянно, планомерно.

Выбор за вами!

Comment: Спасибо большое! :)

Answer (score 0):

Не думаю, что здесь уместна парцелляция. Это же не художественный текст? И, похоже, не публицистика.

Comment: Да, в конце концов, можно просто разбить на три предложения. ))